# Custom post type URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls

I have a page called "News", and I have created a custom post type for news. In "News" page I need to show all news custom posts and they need to be clickable. "News" page url is http://example.com/media/lajmet. When I click on news it goes on url "http://example.com/news/article1". How to rewrite URL on custom post click to go in "http://example.com/media/lajmet/article1" ? Also I am using polylang for languages.

This is how I have create custom post type for news:

```
function news_custom_post() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'News', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'News', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add new', 'news' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add new news' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit news' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New news' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All news' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View news' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search news' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No news found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No news found in the Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'News'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our media news data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'   => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_custom_post' );
```

Comment: Please use example.com when linking to test sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `rewrite` `slug` when you [register your post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'media/lajmet' )
    // other args...
);
```

Comment: Cool it works, but when I click on another language, redirects me to the index.php. I am using polylang

Comment: Also need to go in permalinks after I set the rewrite slug and  to save permalinks without any change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it's not straightforward. When you register a custom post type in WordPress, the first argument of `register_post_type` is the slug that you use. This slug can only be for one URL segment. If you changed it to `media` then all of your articles would take the form `/media/article-slug-here`.

If you want to nest it deeper, you will have to register a rewrite rule to listen for the extra segment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Your add_rewrite_rule call would likely take a format similar to this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^media/lajmet/(.*+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=news&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
```